# Pass a variable thru ajax to external php file then have it insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a local web app I am creating and am currently running wamp server.
MySQL tables are created and php is working.  I've put php extensions on my files instead of html.  I have a simple webpage with a text box input for a first name and a button that runs a function to pass the variable to an external php file which connects to my database.  I am trying to use that variable to insert it into my database but cannot figure it out.

My php page with the text box looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myAjax () {

$.ajax( { type : 'POST',
      data : {'action':document.getElementById('FirstName').value},
      url  : 'queue.php',
      success: function ( data ) {
        alert( data );
      },
      error: function ( xhr ) {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    });
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>


<center><input type="text" name="FirstName" id = "FirstName" value="" ></input></center><br>
<center><button id = "addUser" type="button" onclick = "myAjax()" disabled>+Add User</button></center><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my external php file residing in the same directory as my webpage looks like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["my_data"] = $_POST['action']; // STORE VALUE IN VARIABLE.
echo "data received = " . $_SESSION["my_data"]; // RETURN VALUE TO CONFIRM.


$servername = "localhost";
$database = "Users";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection

 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

  }
   echo "Connected successfully";
   $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (singer) VALUES ('I can insert a value here but want the value of my variable that was passed over')";
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


 ?>
```

Comment: your starting file is index.php(on the server), inside it you generate the html code(which generates at user).

Comment: Going to have to research that further but it seems to go into the external php file fine and does echo the var that was passed and also connects to the db and inserts a name if I add it to values it just can't figure out how to use the passed variable in my insert statement.

Comment: for insert just check [https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: if your $_REQUEST has the data you wanted you need to create a database and table before inserting

Comment: Thanks I did that already but the only show examples of passing hard coded items not variables.

Comment: Does `echo data received;` or echo $_SESSION["my_data"]; give you your passed value? if so  `$sql = "INSERT INTO queue (singer) VALUES (".$_SESSION["my_data"].")";` also am guessing you maybe new to php if so please read about SQL injections https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Thanx Bobby Axe that worked after a little modification going to update my question with my final solution

Comment: Consider using a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

my Insert statement looks like this now and it works!!

$sql = "INSERT INTO queue (singer) VALUES ('".$_SESSION["my_data"]."')";